# how make select by Getdate()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i want to make select on dte by `Getdate()` in this code

```
 select a.Dte,
  SUM ( p.IMoney - p.OMoney) from Daily a 
  cross join 
  Daily p 
  where a.Dte >= p.Dte 
  group by a.Dte
```

Comment: You question does not make sense.  Do you just want to include getdate() in the select list?

Comment: @Bondye Just a heads-upm, The OP is in MSSQL - not mysql - but yes, do you mean you wish to use the current date in the where clause Tarek? if so, can you clarify what, i.e. where the current date is greater than the Dte columns?

Comment: If you want to say "where this happened today", you can cast GETDATE as a DATE (rather than DATETIME): WHERE a.Dte >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

Comment: `GetDate()` is a moving target.  That impacts query efficiency and results.  In most cases it makes more sense to capture the current date/time in a variable and use that value in the query.